# How to use $firebaseArray in firebase return data in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I want to retrieve data from firbase with a condition like this

```
ref.orderByChild('users').equalTo(userid).on('value', function(snapshot) {
    // Need to return data as firebaseArray here
});
```

$firebaseArray is very useful when we want to show data on view. But I don't know how to return the **snapshot** there.

Please help me ! (bow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `$firebaseArray` can take in a ref or a query.

```
var query = ref.orderByChild('users').equalTo(userid);
var syncArray = $firebaseArray(query);
```

The array function handles all the child events and keeps the array in sync with the remote server changes.

Comment: Thanks David. Exactly what I want !